# Clustering from an Affinity Matrix in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am attempting to locate clusters of like objects.  I have computed a value for each object-to-object comparison and created a matrix of the form:

```
header =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
matrix = [[0, 100, 0, 0, 0]
          [100, 0, 0, 0, 0]
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I pass the matrix to the sklearn Affinity Propagation module:

```
matrix = np.array(matrix)
cluster = AffinityPropagation(preference="precomputed")
cls = cluster.fit_predict(matrix)
```

In the example given, I would expect 1 and 2 to be clustered, as 1-2 / 2-1 is 100, and all other values are zero.  But the cls array does not reflect this:

```
cls = [0 0 0 0 1]
```

Which indicates that 1, 2, 3, and 4 are one cluster, and 5 is a separate cluster.

I've attempted passing the upper right triangular matrix, varying the value magnitude (ie 0-1 vice 0-100) etc, and it does not cluster as expected.

Thoughts on what I am missing?

ADDITIONAL INFO 10/24/2014:

I am performing a pairwise comparison of my objects, and from that I generate a number that indicates how well each object relates with every other.  Many of these objects do not relate at all, so they result in a "0" value.

This creates a sparse n-by-n matrix, where n is on the order of 10s to 100s of objects.

Visually, it is trivial for me to "cluster" these objects for further analysis.  In the below case 1 relates to 2, and 2 relates to 3, but 1 and 3 do not DIRECTLY relate.  I would continue processing with 1, 2, and 3, and ignore 4 and 5.  (In my actual data, I would likely have multiple valid clusters within a single matrix).

```
header =  [1,   2,   3,   4,   5]
matrix = [[0,  100,  0,   0,   0]
          [100, 0,  96,  0,  0]
          [0,  96,  0,   0,   0]
          [0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
          [0,   0,   0,   0,   0]]
```

My research indicates that Affinity Propagation is good at finding clusters in sparse matrices, and and my pairwise comparison is effectively generating a "precomputed" affinity matrix.

While it is easy to find these clusters visually, I would like to automate it so I can integrate it with the code that comes before and after.  However, as the original post indicates, I am not generating meaningful clusters.

The question:

Is some kind of processing required to generate meaningful clusters starting with the kind of matrix I have described?

Am I neglecting a step or otherwise inserting an error into the algorithm such that it fails to find my clusters?

Should I be using a different clustering method (DBSCAN, k-means, etc) on this kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

0 is not a magic "do not link" value.

Since the affinity of objects 3 and 4 is the *same* to 1, 2, or 5, it does not matter where they are assigned to; they are all roughly of the same quality.

The stronger cohesion of 1 and 2 may make it preferrable to assign 3 and 4 there; and the desire to produce more than once cluster may yield that 5 remains separate. But it may also just be random, object 3 and 4 get assigned to the first exemplar of best affinity (being from cluster 1,2); and object 5 is just kept separate to have at least two components.

Use real data, not hand-crafted affinities.

Comment: There must be a value that represents "do not link." (really, "link is very weak.")  A human being looking at this data would readily find a cluster of 1-2 and a cluster of 3-4-5.  That the algorithm misses it implies that I am using it wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should give 3-4-5 a higher affinity than 0 then.

Comment: I tried replacing the zeros with: 0.1, 10, and 90.  All three attempts produced cls = [0 0 0 0 1].  My (basic) research pointed me to the Affinity Propagation method because I have a sparse matrix (many cases where no linkage is observed), and AP is efficient for such a matrix.

Comment: I didn't say replace all zeros. Just those of 3,4,5 if you want them to link.

Comment: OK... How?  If I write code that changes the value of "empty" row/columns it works for the simple case above (if I fill in row/col 3,4,5 with say -10, it now groups 1-2 and 3-4-5.)  But if I create clusters 1-2 and 3-4 and leave 5 empty (filled in with -10 by my new code) it now creates cluster 1-2-3-4 and cluster 5, which is not right.  What is the algorithm for "replace the zeros if you want them to link"?

Comment: The right approach then probably is to use a different clustering algorithm altogether, like some of constraint clustering approaches; or a classic graph algorithm instead of anything matrix based (which won't scale to large data anyway!)